# How to create an ISO file of a Boot Camp partition from OS X?

Tags: macos, partitioning, boot-camp, iso-image

How do I create an ISO file of a Boot Camp partition from OS X to use the ISO in Parallels later?

I thought Winclone could do it, but it can't.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Can't Parallels just boot the Boot Camp partition like that?

Comment: The boot camp partition and Parallels are on different Mac's. But yes, Parallels can.

Answer (score 2):

Use Disk Utility to do it. Select your partition and hit the "New Image" button. In the Save sheet that pops up, set the Image Format to "DVD/CD Master". Disk Utility will suggest a filename extension of `.cdr` for the resulting disk image, but just change it to `.iso`. They're just different names for the same thing.

Comment: Cool, thanks! And this image should boot under Parallels then?

Comment: @Aron You'll have to tell me. I don't use Parallels.

Answer (score 2):

`.CDR` and `.ISO` files are **not** the same thing.  You can convert your `.CDR` file to an `.ISO` file by using Terminal in Mac OS X.

Let's use a file named `BOOTCAMP.cdr` for my example.

Follow these steps:
1. Move `BOOTCAMP.cdr` file (created by Disk Utility) to the desktop of your Mac.
2. Start Terminal.
3. Type: `cd ~/desktop` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Type: `hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o BOOTCAMP.iso BOOTCAMP.cdr` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Close Terminal.

*Enjoy!!!*